# biblatex with bibtex alphabetic all upper case

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

i am trying to get my whole bibliography to have shorthandles with Upper case.

I am using:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,urldate=comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib/literatur.bib}
\printbibliography
```

I found this solution:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[uppercase,final]{shorthand}
    \field[uppercase]{label}
    \field[uppercase,strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[uppercase,strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}
```

But this does not work. I also cleaned the workspace.
I still do have lower case letters in the shorthandles:

[image]

If you need further informations let me know in comments. The full header is Huge so i dont want to post this here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `uppercase=true` should work.

```
\field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1,uppercase=true]{labelname}
\field[strwidth=1,strside=left,uppercase=true]{labelname}
```

I must comment, however, that this format effectively removes any way to distinguish between a three author work and a single author work, which I don't think is very practical.

Here's a working minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
 \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1,uppercase=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,uppercase=true]{labelname}
          }
 \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=right]{year}
          }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,baez/article,baez/online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This actually does not change anything. I added the `=true` to all upercase things in the labelelement.

I'd need a style that only makes all letter upper case. Everything else is fine. But the "up/down" of the labeles is a nightmare...

Comment: @BennX You are using the `bibtex` backend.  This solution requires `biber`.  So you need to remove `backend=bibtex` from your code, delete all your aux files and then recompile using `latex` `biber` `latex`.

Comment: if i  run it with my bib it does not work. second ill add the minimal and parts of my bib

Comment: My fault. It does work with Biber as backend. There was an issue in my .bib which i needed to fix. any idea how i can get a name for things like: 
`@misc{CouchDB,
 title = {Apache CouchDB: A Database for the Web},
 url = {http://couchdb.apache.org},
 urldate = {2015-12-19}
}` like this they do have a empty name.

Comment: @BennX That sounds like a separate question. You would also have to decide what kind of output would be desirable in this case. If you do post a new question, please take a look at the bibliography section of this [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to see how to include a sample `.bib` entry in your example code, and make sure the code you post is completely minimal (like my example document).